# Throw error to calling method!

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors

I have a thread class and in the run method I am making a call to a web service, this call is in a try catch

```
try {
    // Make webs service call
}
catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
```

Eclipse doesn't like this!

Basically I want to throw this error to the calling method and deal with it there?

Comment: what do you mean by "Eclipse doesn't like this!"?

Comment: Unhandled exception type Exception

Comment: "throw this error to the calling method", I doubt this is possible, the calling method lives on another thread...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you throw a checked exception, the exception must be handled either with try/catch or declaring it as thrown in the method signature. See the [exceptions tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html); particularly the part about [The Three Kinds of Exceptions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html).

Comment: There is also something about method overriding here. as [I added in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976764/throw-error-to-calling-method/5976800#5976800)

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are overriding `run()` and overriding won't allow you to declare broader exception to be thrown. You can wrap it up in `RuntimeException`.

Do it something like

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try{
                   //your code
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);//or appropriate RuntimeException
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }
```

Comment: The signature of [Runnable.run](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html#run%28%29) does not declare that it throws any Exception, so you cannot throw a checked exception from it.

Answer (score 3):

Yep `java.lang.Exception` is checked, so you can't throw it (as Runnable.run does not declare any Exceptions in its throws clause; it doesn't have a throws clause).  You could only throw RunTimeExceptions.  You'll have to handle the Checked Exceptions - that's what Java is forcing you to do.  One approach is to convert the Checked Exception into a RunTimeException so you can throw it.  But don't forget this is a separate thread, so watch your handling logic.

```
public class ThreadFun implements Runnable {

    public void run()  {

        // LEGAL
        try {

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw e;
        }

        // NOT LEGAL
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of catching the exception, add `throws Exception` to the method signature. This will force the calling method to catch the exception instead.

Comment: As said in the thread, this will not work as Runnable.run does not have a throws Clause.